# How to target a parent class in CSS?

Tags: css

Is there a way to target a parent class in CSS?

```
<div class="accountarea">
    <a class="auglink" href="/account">
        Account <i class="fa fa-angle-down icon-right"></i>
    </a>
    <div class="accountappear">
        <div class="accountforce">
            You are not logged in to an account.
            <form action="account.php" method="post">
                <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="E-mail Address" />
                <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
                <input type="submit" name="login" value="Log In" class="minisubmit" />
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="accountbottom">
            ddd
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need it so that if any input field in `accountarea` is on focus (`:focus`), then `accountarea` should stay visible (it's currently set to go visible on hover - I need both).

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't wan to do this with jQuery or JavaScript?

Comment: Its discussed at length here, have a look  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a way to select the parent element with CSS right now.

Using JavaScript is currently your best option.

If jQuery is already loaded on your page see the docs on [Tree Traversal](https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/)